# CakePHP Association problems

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm having quite some issues understanding the way CakePHP does his association.
Consider the following database configuration:

[image]

I'm doing the relationships in the CakePHP code, like this:

AbstractComponent

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * AbstractComponent Model
 *
 */
class AbstractComponent extends AppModel {
/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'id';

    public $hasOne = array(
        'DetailComponent' => array(
            'className' => 'DetailComponent',
            'foreignKey' => 'component_id'
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'TargetComponent' => array(
            'className' => 'ListComponent',
            'foreignKey' => 'target_component_id'
        ),
        'ListComponent' => array(
            'className' => 'ListComponent',
            'foreignKey' => 'component_id'
        )
    );

}
```

ListComponent

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * ListComponent Model
 *
 */
class ListComponent extends AppModel {
/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'id';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'AbstractComponent' => array(
            'className' => 'AbstractComponent',
            'foreignKey' => 'component_id'
        )
    );

    public $hasOne = array(
        'TargetComponent' => array(
            'className' => 'TargetComponent',
            'foreignKey' => 'list_component_id'
        )
    );
}
```

TargetComponent

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * TargetComponent Model
 *
 */
class TargetComponent extends AppModel {
/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'id';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'ListComponent' => array(
            'className' => 'ListComponent',
            'foreignKey' => 'list_component_id'
        )
    );
}
```

DetailComponent

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * DetailComponent Model
 *
 */
class DetailComponent extends AppModel {
/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'title_label_text';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'AbstractComponent' => array(
            'className' => 'AbstractComponent',
            'foreignKey' => 'component_id'
        )
    );
}
```

How come that whenever I get to my Add view of the TargetComponents I can't select a List Component?
How do I access those objects? All the other relationships are working normally and I can select the ID that corresponds to a record in my database.

This is my controller's add function:

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->TargetComponent->create();
            if ($this->TargetComponent->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The target component has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The target component could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }

        $list_components = $this->TargetComponent->ListComponent->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('list_components'));
    }
```

and my view:

```
<div class="targetComponents form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('TargetComponent');?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Target Component'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('type');
        echo $this->Form->input('list_components_id');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
    <ul>

        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Target Components'), array('action' => 'index'));?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm stuck, and clearly doing something horrendously wrong.

Help is MUCH appreciated!

Thanks in advance

-B

Comment: +1 on the question for your great attention to detail and including an EER of your database design, more people should learn to post their questions like this! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the compliment. I like to be really clear about my code and all it's peripherals. I also feel that people should be doing this more often considering the fact that it makes helping each other out way easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested this on my local Cake environment with some dummy values in the database (1 for int fields and `Test` for varchar fields). It turns out that everything is actually properly associated, but the problem lies within the view.

For some reason Cake doesn't automagically put the values in the `list_components_id` dropdown (while by convention it should put the `$list_components` array in there). Forcing the options makes it work for me. So, in the view, replace:

```
echo $this->Form->input('list_components_id');
```

With this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('list_components_id', array('options' => $list_components));
```

This does the trick for me and populates the dropdown with the id's from the ListComponents model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's quite unclear why CakePHP does not 'automagically' find the bindings.

Comment: @Bryan Yeah, I don't understand why either. AFAIK this behaviour hasn't changed in 2.0, so there was nothing wrong with the way you were thinking in the first place :)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this particular issue. Is there some easier way we could communicate? I think I can learn a lot from you!

Comment: @Bryan I hang around in the CakePHP IRC channel quite often, using the same nickname :)